# How do dataframes/datasets compile down to RDDs?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, optimization, memory, rdd

I've been reading on the improvements of DataFrames/Datasets compared to RDDs: Tungsten row format, code generation, etc. Some texts seem to imply that DataFrames/Datasets are converted to RDDs as part of the optimizer pipeline. Is this correct?

*Spark: The definitive guide* says:

> Physical planning results in a series of RDDs and transformations. This is why you might have heard Spark referred to as a compiler - it takes queries in DataFrames, Datasets and SQL and compiles them into RDD transformations for you.

And on slide 10 of the slideset below we see RDDs as the end result of the optimizer pipeline.
https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/sparksql-a-compiler-from-queries-to-rdds

But if I understand correctly, DataFrames and Datasets are stored in memory in the Tungsten row format while RDDs are stored as Java objects. Does this mean that when we perform a query (which gets processed by the optimizer) on a DataFrame, we eventually end up with Java objects instead of Tungsten rows?

Thanks in advance